# How to capture a screenshot when a specific assert failed in CasperJS?

Tags: javascript, casperjs

Is it possible to capture a screenshot when a specific `assert` fails? 
I see in doc and forums that it's possible to do a global process when the test catches a fail like this:

```
casper.test.on("fail", function (failure) {
  // Do something, "casper.capture" for example
});
```

But I want a specifical process for each `assert`. I mean:

```
test.assertTitle(...) // if it fails, do this
test.assertMatch(...) // if it fails, do that
...
```

Is it possible? How can I do that?

Answer (score 4):

After google/forum/code searches, I find it =)

```
try{
  test.assertxxx(...)
} catch (e) {
  casper.fail("It's a fail!");
}
```